# What are ways in which an arbitrary number of nested loops be created in Fortran?

Tags: loops, recursion, nested, fortran, fortran90

What are ways in which an arbitrary number of nested loops be created in Fortran? For example, in such a way that the number of nested loops k can be determined at runtime:

```
do i1 = 1,n1
do i2 = 1,n2
do i3 = 1,n3
do i4 = 1,n4
...
! use i1,i2,i3,i4,....,ik for something
...
enddo
enddo
enddo
enddo
```

Comment: I once had to do that, as a very basic and bad solution to a certain problem (in C).  In a nutshell, as far as I recall, I had a wrapper script that wrote out the file with needed nested loops and then compiled and ran the project that used it. It actually worked.

Comment: This does rather invite the question *Why do you want to do this ?*  For example, if you look around SO you'll find questions asking how to make arbitrary-depth loop nests to which the answer is *Use an* `elemental` *function*.  For others a recursive approach is appropriate. So, why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I want to to this to transform a tensor of arbitrary rank and still have a code which looks "transparent" in terms of the physics.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, you need to make nested loops (and usually one wants to keep nested loops to a minimum).

But at compile time, you don't even know how many nests you need to do.

If I had that problem, I would probably unwrap the nests into a single loop, and calculate the various indices from scratch. Here's an example that I have just tried out:

```
program nested
    implicit none
    integer :: num_nests, i
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: nest_limits
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: nests

    print *, "Please enter number of nests:"
    read(*, *) num_nests
    allocate(nest_limits(num_nests))
    allocate(nests(num_nests))

    print *, "Please enter nest limits:"
    read(*, *) nest_limits

    nests(:) = 1
    outer_loop : do
        print *, nests(:)
        i = 1
        ! Calculate the next indices:
        inner_loop : do  
            nests(i) = nests(i) + 1 

            ! If this is still a valid index, exit the inner 
            ! loop and go for the next iteration
            if (nests(i) <= nest_limits(i)) exit inner_loop

            ! The index has overflown, so reset it to 1 and
            ! move to next index.
            nests(i) = 1
            i = i + 1

            ! If the next index would be outside of num_nests, 
            ! the whole loop is finished.
            if (i > num_nests) exit outer_loop

        end do inner_loop
    end do outer_loop
end program nested
```

Answer (score 0):

The method as provided by chw21 worked. However I quickly ran into problems for deep nested loops. The workload became too heavy to handle. Luckily in my case only indices that were distinct were of interest. Moreover the order did not matter, i.e. the indices 5,3,2 would yield the same result as 2,3,5. Basically the problem degenerated to providing all the combinations on a lottery ticket. If your problem is of such a nature the code below might be of interest.

```
program indices
implicit none
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: ns
integer   :: i,j,k,ni,np,nt,ntmp
integer*8 :: nc

print *, "Number of towns to visit"
read(*, *) np
allocate(ns(np))

print *, "Total number of towns"
read(*, *) nt

if (nt<=0) then
  print*,' Error: Please provide a positive value'
  stop
endif

if(nt<np) then
   print*,' Error: Number of towns to visit must be less'
   print*,'        than or eqaul to total number of towns.'
   stop
endif

! Initialize .....
do i=1,np
  ns(i)=i   
enddo
ntmp=nt-np
nc=0
! ................
print*,' Combinations of towns to visit..:' 
do 
   print*,ns(:)
   ! Do the appropriate work with ns here.
   !          .......
   !
   ! Provide a new combination:
   nc=nc+1
   if (ns(np)<nt) then
      ns(np)=ns(np)+1
   elseif (ns(1)==(ntmp+1)) then
      exit
   else
      do i=2,np
        if(ns(i)==(ntmp+i)) then
           ni=ns(i-1)
           k=0
           do j=i-1,np
              k=k+1
              ns(j)=ni+k
           enddo
           exit
         endif
      enddo
  endif
enddo
print*,' Number of combinations..........:',nc
end program indices
```